# Referring to an object that is created later in the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I'm making a python app and I have a class with a function that changes a variable created after the class. I can't put that variable before the class because that variable refers to variables inside the class and I end up with a paradox. It looks something like this:

```
class LeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        #Casual__init__Stuff

    def LeFunction(self):
        A = 1

A = LeClass()
```

Anyone got a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Declare the variable `A` global before assigning it from within your class code:

```
global A
A = 1
```

Otherwise, A will be a local variable that goes out of scope (is not accessible anymore) after the method returns.

Answer (score 0):

Just tell python to look for the variable outside the class first when you try to use that variable.

Here is the code :

```
class LeClass:
def __init__(self):
    pass
    #Casual__init__Stuff

def LeFunction(self):
    global A
    A = 1


A = LeClass()
print("First Print :", A)
A.LeFunction()
print("Second Print :", A)
```

And here is the output of the code :

```
First Print : <__main__.LeClass object at 0x7f2ba3f1bb38>
Second Print : 1
```